# Print bounding box in the terminal

Tags: javascript, object-oriented, programming-challenge, node.js

Right now I am finding ways to write better code in javascript and I see many coding styles used by different authors but right now I am thinking to write code which adheres to the object oriented paradigm better suited for this type of language.

**Code**

```
// Terminal

'use strict';

class Terminal {
  constructor() {
    this.cols = process.stdout.columns || 80
    this.rows = process.stdout.rows || 60
  }

  width() {
    return this.cols
  }

  height() {
    return this.rows
  }
}

module.exports = Terminal


// Box

'use strict';

const Terminal = require('./terminal')

class Box {
  constructor(opts) {
    let terminal = new Terminal()
    const defaults = {
      w: terminal.width(),
      h: terminal.height(),
      t: '══',
      tr: '╗',
      r: '║',
      br: '╝',
      b: '══',
      bl: '╚',
      l: '║',
      tl: '╔',
      fill: '░░'
    }
    this.settings = Object.assign(defaults, opts)
  }

  toString() {
    const res = [];
    const { t, tr, r, br, b, bl, l, tl } = this.settings
    const { w , h } = this.settings
    // Filling row wise
    for (let i = 0; i < h; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < w; j++) {
        if (i === 0 && j === 0) {
          res.push(tl)
        }
        else if (i === 0 && j === w - 1) {
          res.push(tr)
        }
        else if ((i === h - 1) && (j === w - 1)) {
          res.push(br)
        }
        else if ((i === h - 1) && j === 0) {
          res.push(bl)
        }
        else if (this.isFirstRow(i) || this.isLastRow(i)) {
          res.push(t)
        }
        else if (this.isFirstCol(j) || this.isLastCol(j)) {
          res.push(l)
        }
        else {
          const { fill } = this.settings
          res.push(fill)
        }
      }
      res.push('\n')
    }
    return res.join('')
  }

  isFirstRow(row) {
    return row === 0
  }

  isLastRow(row) {
    const { h } = this.settings
    return row === h - 1
  }

  isFirstCol(col) {
    return col === 0
  }

  isLastCol(col) {
    const { w } = this.settings
    return col === w - 1
  }
}

class TopRight {
  constructor() {
    this.symbol = '╗'
  }

  toString() {
    return this.symbol
  }
}

class BottomRight {
  constructor() {
    this.symbol = '╝'
  }

  toString() {
    return this.symbol
  }
}

class BottomLeft {
  constructor() {
    this.symbol = '╚'
  }

  toString() {
    return this.symbol
  }
}

class TopLeft {
  constructor() {
    this.symbol = '╔'
  }

  toString() {
    return this.symbol
  }
}

module.exports = Box

// O/P
/*
> const B = require('./box')
> console.log(new B({w: 8, h: 8, fillSymbol: '||'}).toString())
╔════════════╗
║░░░░░░░░░░░░║
║░░░░░░░░░░░░║
║░░░░░░░░░░░░║
║░░░░░░░░░░░░║
║░░░░░░░░░░░░║
║░░░░░░░░░░░░║
╚════════════╝
*/
```

I would like to know how to improve the above code to make better use of prototypal inheritance and delegation which is widely advocated in javascript world.

**Note**

I thought to use classes for printing symbols but I see that they make code more bloated. I left them there hear opinion of others.

Comment: This seems _really_ over-engineered.  It looks like you want a function that, given a width and height, returns a string box of that width and height, filled with some symbol?  Is that correct?  Because if so, that should be a single function which is 5-10 lines long.

Comment: @Jonah show me the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be order of magnitudes simpler.  You want a function that takes a width, height, and optional fill character, and returns a string (your box).

Try this:

```
function box(w, h, fill='░░') {
  const top    = '╔' + '══'.repeat(w-2) + '╗\n' 
  const row    = '║' + fill.repeat(w-2) + '║\n'
  const bottom = '╚' + '══'.repeat(w-2) + '╝'
  return top + row.repeat(h-2) + bottom
}
```

Comment: And here it goes, you hard coded the symbols.

Comment: Nothing is going anywhere.  That's trivial to fix with an optional parameter.  This is the reason I asked you what you wanted in the comment of the OP.  Are there more requirements than specifying fill and corner symbols?

Comment: Hi, I now see a serious flaw in my thinking process which is directly jumping into the complex solution in the need to become perfectionist. I think it would be good to try the simplest solution possible first followed by refactoring to make the code more flexible and testable, right?

Comment: Yes, always start with the simplest possible thing.  This will 1) clarify your thinking and 2) may be all you end up needing.  Re: testing, note that the above is _trivially testable_.  In fact, as a general rule, nothing is easier to test than pure functions: you know what output you expect for given input, and you write tests to assert that, when given the input, your function produces the expected output.  When you make objects testable, you typically do so with dependency injection, which is really just a fancy way of passing in input.

Comment: Yes, and I am really trying hard to learn this process of thinking, can you please suggest me some book or course? and let me tell you this is part of a bigger problem and I am learning to break the problem in smaller pieces as part of the learning process.

Comment: Sure, are you asking for resources on approaching problems in a functional style in particular, or problem solving in general?

Comment: What you think I am lacking?

Comment: that's a big question i'm not qualified to answer.  i know only the problem in this one snippet of code.  but as for practical advice that you can't go too far wrong with, learn some functional programming.  if you're doing it javascript, start using ramda.js.  here's a [massive list of resources](https://github.com/xgrommx/awesome-functional-programming).  for FP in general, there are a number of free MOOCs, but i can't offer advice on the best one.  and keep posting here.  hard to beat practice and direct feedback. good luck!

Comment: What about solving problem in functional style, I know the books like SICP but I think they are more into creating a function or so. What about solving a complex problem in functional style?

Answer (score 2):

I think you and @jonah just have to meet in the middle.  So if you'll both allow me:

1. Yes, using classes for each printing symbol is definitely too much.  As Jonah says, it is better to just let that be an optional parameter and let it be used as a simple string.  To put it simply, your TopRight, BottomRight, TopLeft, and BottomLeft classes definitely violate the principle of [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).  If those characters needed more functionality than simply storing the character to be outputted, then I would suggest (in this case), having a single class that had four *instances* (i.e. local variables) named TopRight, BottomRight, etc..  The only thing different between those classes is the class name and default character: no reason for a separate class as-is.
2. Jonah's code really *is* orders of magnitude simpler.  Now granted, you are trying to practice proper OOP design, and his example does the opposite (making it all one quick function), but his algorithm is a much more elegant solution.  It will have better performance and it is substantially easier to understand.  So I would suggest you effectively replace your `to_string` method with his `box` method.  Granted, you still want to work within your OOP paradigm and replace his hard-coded characters with the settings that come from your object, but his simpler algorithm will do your package a whole lot of good.
3. Here's your biggest problem from an OOP design principle:

`let terminal = new Terminal()`

This is a clear violation of the 'D' in solid, the [dependency inversion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle).  What if the developer is operating within a non-terminal interface, but still wants to use your code?  How are you going to test the default behavior of your system in your testing environment?  You are always going to get this terminal object, whos behavior will be very undetermined in anything other than a console environment.  Inversion of control can be a surprisingly large topic to unpack, so this is something best left to google if you are unfamiliar with its principles.  Obviously you have other ways for the "user" to set the width and height of the box, but that line is still a very clear violation of IoC.

As a potential solution that might better adhere to the [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), you could change the constructor argument for your `Box` class from `opts` (a simple object) to a `settings` interface, which has those same defined keys.  Then you could build a `terminal` class which implements the `settings` interface and loads its width and height out of the console by default and also accepts an optional width, height, characters, etc.  Therefore, your calling sequence would look like this:

```
const B = require('./box')
const Terminal = require('./terminal');
console.log( new B( new Terminal( {w: 8, h:8, fillSymbol: '||'} ) ).toString() )
```

Those are my thoughts, anyway.  Obviously, I've left out some details, but I think the intent should be clear.  Obviously javascript doesn't have interfaces, but the same concepts apply.

Comment: The problem is this just isn't a good example to practice OOP design on.  A utility function is the perfect fit.  If you _really_ want to make my design OO, what you'd do have is have a constructor function to which you'd pass w, h, fill (+ other optional args if desired) , which returns a `Box` object, with methods like `toString()` (returns what my example does), `width()`, etc.  Having classes like `TopRight`, `BottomLeft`, etc, is just _terrible_ design.  My intention here is not to be mean, but it's important OP realize this, and sugar-coating it isn't doing him any favors.

Comment: I agree: this is easily a utility function without need for any fuss.  However, you can try to apply OOP principles to anything, and simpler things are easier to break down, so it isn't a crazy question to ask.  I don't have any problem with your answer, and don't think you are trying to be mean.  My goal was simply to answer the question as asked, which is why I mentioned pretty much those same points you have here.

Comment: Yeah, it's tough.  I see what you're trying to do.  And in theory you're right -- it's a fine question to ask.  The problem is, practically speaking, I look at the code and I _know_ the best advice that can possibly be given, if the person is willing to listen, is: _Don't.  Just stop right there.  Do it simply.  Do it with functions.  You don't need OOP._  My current belief is that it's only possible to write decent OO code if you already know FP well and can approach OO with a largely immutable style.  But if you know FP that well, you won't even desire to do it.

Comment: @ConorMancone since javascript doesn't have interfaces so I think you mean duck typing, right? Also, If I think more about it passing symbols like `t, tr, r etc` feels weird because those are nor properties of a terminal but can be properties of a box, wdyt?

Comment: @CodeYogi yes, duck typing is the way to go.  Regarding passing symbols (if I understand you correctly), what you are getting at is exactly the point of SOLID.  Right now your class is very specific: print out a box for a terminal.  By taking the terminal out though, and simply specifying the some properties of the object that gets passed in, it becomes much more reusable and testable.  It can be reused for any number of cases that you don't specifically have to plan for: anyone who wants to use it just has to abide by the "contract" for your input.

Comment: I think it would be good to pass two objects to the Box object 1) Terminal and 2) BoxDescription or something like that, the BoxDescription should contain the symbols used, wdyt?

Comment: You could go with one or two parameters.  In these things, there is definitely plenty of room for doing things different ways.  Usually the way to break it down is along the lines of the single responsibility principle.   Each class should be responsible for "one" thing.  In this case, your terminal object just tells you about width and height.  This is a display setting, so it isn't crazy to also put symbols in there (another display setting).  However, if you know those pieces of information might commonly come from different things, it is reasonable to split it out into two classes.